# amp-img and defining size in context of media size

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I'm wondering if I can define size of the AMP image not only for two different width's but for example for three 
or even four:

```
<amp-img
    media="(min-width: 650px)"
    src="wide.jpg"
    width=466
    height=355 layout="responsive" ></amp-img>
<amp-img
    media="(max-width: 649px)"
    src="narrow.jpg"
    width=527
    height=193 layout="responsive" ></amp-img>
```

I tried to achieve it by parallel definiton of `min-width` and `max-width` but it doesn't seem to work. 
Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you can use the `srcset` attribute. More info can be found [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-img).